# Clean a URL then print in javascript

Tags: javascript, url, printing

I should print the URL in an under construction page.
But if I get the url w/

```
var url = window.location;
document.write("    <p>"+url+"</p>");
```

I get something like "http://mypage.ass/trololo/pageasd/.../index.html"

But I need simply "mypage.ass", nothing else.

I tried to clean it with substring but every browser said that it is not a function. -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need split the url:

```
var localUrl = document.URL
localUrl = localUrl.split('http://')[1].split('/');
document.write("<p>"+localUrl[0]+"</p>");
```

BTW:User document.URL can avoid confusion when your service redirect

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.hostname` instead of `window.location`. The latter has no `.split`.

```
var myass = window.location.hostname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let JavaScript do the work:

```
document.write("<p>" + location.hostname + "</p>");
```

The location object also has other useful properties, for reference see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: Looks like its also a solution, thy. :)

Answer (score -1):

This may work if your domain is 3 char long:

```
var url = "mypage.ass/ilikepies";
url.substring(url.indexOf(":") + 2, url.indexOf(".") + 3)
```

Comment: This does not really make sense because it only works if the domain length is static - in which case you can also just hardcode the domain itself...